# Django query ManyToMany relationship from parent=ForeignKey('self')

Tags: python, django

This is for a Django blog project. I have a model 'Profile' and 'TechStackCategory' where they have a ManyToMany relationship. Profile is the user's profile for the blog. TechStackCategory has categories of the user's stacks that they know.

TechStackCategory model example: Languages, Languages -> Python, Languages -> Java, Frameworks, Frameworks -> Django

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
background_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_background_pics', blank=True, null=True,)
bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="200 characters or less")
tech_stack_cat = models.ManyToManyField('TechStackCategory', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user.username}'s profile"

class TechStackCategory(models.Model):
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title}"

class Meta:
    #enforcing that there can not be two categories under a parent with same slug

    # __str__ method elaborated later in post.  use __unicode__ in place of

    unique_together = ('title', 'parent',)    
    verbose_name_plural = "categories"     

def __str__(self):                           
    full_path = [self.title]                  
    k = self.parent
    while k is not None:
        full_path.append(k.title)
        k = k.parent
    return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])
```

So I'm following the example from this post https://dev.to/shivamrohilla/how-to-make-a-sub-and-sub-sub-categories-in-django-most-important-216p

The thing is, the example in the post shows all the parents and children objects from the Category model. He filters out the query in the views as `catg = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)` which returns `<QuerySet [<TechStackCat: Languages>, <TechStackCat: Frameworks>]>`

**I would like to do the same but add an additional filter to filter    out the user's categories.**

```
views.py
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
user = self.request.user
catg = TechStackCategory.objects.filter(profile__user=user).all().filter(parent=None)
context ['catg'] = catg
```

**right now this returns empty so it's not working. `<QuerySet []>`**

and `TechStackCat.objects.filter(profile__user=user).all()` returns `<QuerySet [<TechStackCat: Languages -> Python>, <TechStackCat: Languages -> Java>]>`

to follow the posts' example I need to grab the parent object.

[image]

or another option for me is I can run below so I don't have duplicate parents. (Ex: Languages, Languages, Languages -> Python, Languages -> Java) I just need to show ([Languages -> Python, Java],[Frameworks -> Django])

```
parent_list = []
catg = TechStackCategory.objects.filter(profile__user=user).all()
for c in catg:
    if c.parent not in parent_list:
        parent_list.append(c.parent)
```

but I think the best way to handle this is to make `TechStackCategory.objects.filter(profile__user=user).all().filter(parent=None)` work

sorry I know this is messy.. your help is appreciated..

edit--

So in my admin panel (profile model), I had selected as per below:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically grab the parent object (Languages) as well just from selecting (Languages -> Python)

edit--

So I selected the parent object (Languages) in the admin panel and it shows up like how I want it to..

[image]

but I'm wondering if there's a way to grab the parent object (Languages) just from selecting (Languages -> Python)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you've written in principle, although the format is a little off. The filter can be a single statement and the `all()` call is unnecessary:

```py
TechStackCategory.objects.filter(profile__user=user, parent=None)
```

You said that the queryset that is being created just from the profile filter is this:

> and TechStackCat.objects.filter(profile__user=user).all() returns <QuerySet [<TechStackCat: Languages -> Python>, <TechStackCat: Languages -> Java>]>

Which would be two objects that both have `Languages` as parent objects, both would fail the `parent=None` filter. The queryset also does not return the `Languages` category itself, presumably because it isn't linked to the User. Thus you do not have any objects which satisfy both conditions that they are a) connected to the User and b) an ultimate parent category.